# Are CouchDB filters limited to the _changes feed?

Tags: couchdb

As specified [here](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html#filters), a filter can be used with the _changes feed like this:

```
curl "$HOST/db/_changes?filter=app/important"
```

Now I am trying to use this pattern with a standard view access, like this:

```
curl -X GET $HOST/db/_design/live_data/_view/all-comments&filter=live_data/bytag?tag=testing
```

I have also tried ? instead of &:

```
curl -X GET $HOST/db/_design/live_data/_view/all-comments?filter=live_data/bytag?tag=testing
```

But the filter has no effect: all documents are shown, even those which should not be validated by the filter.

The filter that I am using is:

```
function(doc, req)
{
  for( var i in doc.tags ) {
    if(doc.tags[i] == req.query.tag) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

- Am I doing something wrong in the curl calls?
- Is it at all possible to use views together with filters, or are filters limited to the `_changes` feed? I have seen no examples of filters except related to `_changes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems that filters are limited to _changes requests only.
If you want to filter data from views, you can use "startkey" and "endkey" parameters with possibly more complex json keys and/or reduce grouping levels to achieve your desired results.

Comment: In fact filters are used in [filtered replication](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication).

Answer (score 1):

If this worked it would impose on CouchDB the responsibility of iterating through all the *view*'s records and execute the *filter* function on them. It is not a good way of doing things, especially when you have the possibility of pre-indexing documents using *views* and arrays of keys (like `[date, tag]`).

But nothing will forbid you of implementing this *filter* in a backend of your own. You would only have to load all the *view* documents from CouchDB, execute the *filter* function on them and return. But that wouldn't be fast.